# New close reasons: unclear, too broad, opinion-based, and custom sub-reasons off-topic

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There will be changes in [close reasons](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in the next few days:

- “not constructive” and “not a real question” are replaced by
- “unclear what you're asking”
- “too broad”
- “primarily opinion-based”
- “off-topic” can be refined with predefined sub-reasons. These sub-reasons can cover common motifs that are not obvious from the site name, or cases where we would formerly have used “too localized”, which will disappear.
- Closed questions will be labelled as “on hold” for 5 days, and “closed” afterwards.

Should we have predefined close reasons?

Comment: "This is Home Improvement, not *Ask Amazon*.", "Not enough information, contact a professional."

Comment: For the predefined off-topic list, we can go with the off topic bullets at http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: A very nice set of close reasons - http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/179/what-should-our-list-of-close-reasons-look-like/180#180

Answer (score 3):

Here are the predefined close reasons from the help page:

- The cost of a job or the price of tools as these will vary between locations and over time.
- Shopping assistance, product recommendations, or brand specific advice.
- Legal questions, including contracts with builders, contractor negotiation, and rental agreements.
- Decorating advice.
- Hobby projects.
- Local building codes or advice limited to your area.
- Ranting. Please try to ask your question without a long complaint.
- Operation of major appliances or questions regarding small appliances.

I'd say that the below off topics that belong on another site don't need a close reason, we'll migrate them instead.

- Cars, motorbikes, boats etc. (Try motor vehicle maintenance and repair.)
- Landscaping. (Try gardening and landscaping.)